# How to use SQLite ODBC Driver with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sqlite

I downloaded and installed the SQLite ODBC Driver from http://ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/.
I had three new ODBC Drivers in my List

```
SQLite (UTF-8) Driver
SQLite ODBC Driver
SQLite3 ODBC Driver
```

Using the SQLite3 ODBC Driver works just fine. But not with UTF-8.

The SQLite ODBC (UTF-8) Driver which I assumed to work in this case just gives me the error message

```
Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zur Datenquelle test


IM002 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zur Datenquelle: test
```

English translation:

```
Error connecting to data source test
IM002 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
Error connecting to data source test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christian Werner, the provider of the SQLite Driver helped me via E-Mail.
It turned out that in the settings of the SQLite3 ODBC Driver the `OEMCP Translation` has to be turned on (By clicking Configure... of the specific User DSN in the ODBC Data Source Administrator)

Now all characters are shown as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In connection string, this translates to OEMCPTranslation parameter:

`connStr="DRIVER={{SQLite3 ODBC Driver}};Database=<path>;OEMCPTranslation=1";`

Answer (score 0):

Today in my case {...} worked, but not {{..}} when coppying tables from the Access database to the SQLite database using VBA:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", _
"ODBC;DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=<path>;OEMCPTranslation=1;", _
acTable, <source table>, <destination table>
```